# Speakhere does NOT record after receive a phone call

Tags: iphone, audio

I'm working on a project that need record and analyze sound, every think is ok when i use speak here.
But when some one call my phone, the record stop and when the app return, it never record again.
 I try to restart the recorder by press record, but i get this error: 
     Error: couldn't get input channel count ('!cat')
     Error: couldn't enable metering (-50)
     ERROR: metering failed
I also try to restart by call StartRecord(....) but nothing different. So anyone can help me

```
if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionEndInterruption)

    THIS->recorder->StartRecord(CFSTR("recordedFile.caf"));
```

Answer (score 1):

An app must stop recording in any audio session interrupt listener begin interruption callback if it ever wants to start recording again.  Otherwise, a force quit and restart by the user may be required.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem with SpeakHere and found this solution by (hours and hours of) trial and error. Try this: get rid of the references to playbackWasInterrupted (commented out below), but leave in the other player-related directives. Somehow this re-enables the recorder! If anyone could explain why this works, I would love to know!

Under void interruptionListener, change

```
else if ((inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionEndInterruption)&& THIS->playbackWasInterrupted))
```

to

```
else if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionEndInterruption)

         //&& THIS->playbackWasInterrupted)
```

and then comment out or delete the "playbackWasInterrupted" line below:

```
{
    // we were playing back when we were interrupted, so reset and resume now
    THIS->player->StartQueue(true);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"playbackQueueResumed" object:THIS];
```

//      THIS->playbackWasInterrupted = NO;

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just from memory - when returning to foreground (in the corresponding notification handler), you need to call

```
AudioSessionSetActive (true)
```

or something similar. As I said, I only read it on a related question - no garanties.
Good Luck, nobi